# Feather format for long term storage since the release of apache arrow 1.0.1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyarrow, feather

As I'm given to understand due to the search of issues in the [Feather Github](https://github.com/wesm/feather), as well as questions in stackoverflow such as [What are the differences between feather and parquet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083405/what-are-the-differences-between-feather-and-parquet), the Feather format was not recommended as long term storage due to [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/) versions being 0.x.x, and considered volatile due to the continuous new releases.

My question is, has this situation changed as of the current Apache Arrow's version, 1.0.1? Is Feather considered stable to use as long term storage?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Feather files (using the v2 -- default -- format version, not the v1 "legacy" version) are stable starting with Apache Arrow 1.0.0.