# CSV, txt can not save data fully when using multiprocessing

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing python and save the result to csv or txt, but saving by csv or txt always lose the data . There are so many value to save run parallelly, I think that.

[image]

I can not use database, because it will open connection and make low performance. Are there any ways to save csv without losing data, or there is some solutions to save data?

Comment: If you try to write in the same file in parallel, then this is normal to loose data. There are parallel file interfaces but this require structured binary data (and it only worth it on devices like SSDs). In general, one need to write data in multiple files from multiple threads (or processes). Files can be merged safely sequentially. The same file can safely be read by multiple threads (or processes). By the way, CSV is meant to be read by humans. It is a poor format for most operations not involving humans. Please consider using another format if you care about performance.

Comment: Thank you , do you have any suggestion for using the format file instead of using csv?

Comment: Feather or parquet are relatively good alternatives supported by many tools/softwares. Regarding your needs, the former may be better than the other. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083405/what-are-the-differences-between-feather-and-parquet) for more information.